# decode a json array object

Tags: php, json

I am having a php function that returns a JSON object.

Running this code:

```
$obj = json_decode($result); print_r($obj);
```

where `$result` is the output of the function. The `$result` is:

```
{"result":[{"name":"name1","title":"title1","type":"1","place":"place1"}, 
{"name":"name2","title":"title2","type":"1","place":"place2"}]}
```

My output is this:

```
stdClass Object ( [result] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => name1 [title] => title1 [type] => 1 [place] => place1 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => name2 [title] => title2 [type] => 1 [place] => place2 ) ))
```

So what I want is to access the name1,title1 and so on value for each of the items.

I tried this:

```
echo $obj->result[0];
```

for getting the first row, but it gives me nothing.

If I try something like this:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
  var_dump ($value);
  foreach ($value as $feature => $item) {
     echo $feature.' =>' .$item;
  }
}
```

It enter the first loop only once (output is an array(2) and the items) and it does not enter the second for loop at all. I know that it has something to do with the arrays and the JSON objects but I cannot make it work.

Any help?

Comment: Instead of `echo` try `var_dump`.

Comment: in recursive loops test value type so know what next step is. Also with json_decode can use second argument TRUE for array rather than object if applicable. Cuts down one type ..personally I prefer working with arrays

Comment: *sidenote:* if you found array easier to handle, use this: `$json_array = json_decode($result, true)`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$json = json_decode($json);

foreach($json->result as $index => $item) {
  // $item is an object now, you can access $item->name, $item->title, etc.
}
```

If you want to loop over each key inside that, you can do a foreach on $item with $key => $value;

Answer (score 2):

`$obj->result[0]` is an object; that's why `echo` isn't working.  Try this: `echo $obj->result[0]->name;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the name , you can probably try this

```
echo $obj->result[0]->name; // which should dereference the appropriate object.
```

Also in the loop, try this as $obj->result is the array and $obj is a single object

```
if($obj && isset($obj->result) && is_array($obj->result)){
foreach ($obj->result as $key => $value) {
  var_dump ($value);
  foreach ($value as $feature => $item) {
      echo $feature.' =>' .$item;
  }
}
}
```